# Как поисковик отнесется к ошибке в title

Tags: seo, продвижение

Если в `title` и `h1` написать `z` вместо `s` будет ли это ошибкой?
К примеру, `nice` и `nize`. При условии, что `nize` это ник

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибка, проиндексирует и будет далее следовать своим внутренним алгоритмам при позиционировании в поисковой выдаче. Всё зависит от того, чего вы хотите достичь.

```
<title>nize - это отлично и супер хорошо!<title>
```

Если на странице будет nice - это отлично и супер хорошо!, то возможно и вероятно робот подумает, что это опечатка. Но сие покрыто мраком и утверждать что-либо нельзя. Плюс будет ли ссылка на этот ник - `https://vk.com/nize` к примеру.

Поисковые системы не раскрывают свои алгоритмы, но можно "улавливать" некоторые закономерности. В низкочастотных сегментах легче ставить эксперименты, но это не означает, что в высоко-конкурентных областях эти закономерности проявят себя.